# Remove the duplicate rows in views (SQL Server 2014 management studio)

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 tables `item` and `memo`. In `item`, `itemId` is the PK and the `itid` is the FK. In `memo` the `memID` is the PK.

I created a view:

```
SELECT     
    dbo.memo.memID, dbo.memo.fullname, dbo.memo.company, 
    dbo.memo.department, dbo.memo.MRnum, dbo.memo.date, 
    dbo.memo.returndate, dbo.memo.remarks, 
    dbo.memo.issuedby, dbo.memo.picture, dbo.item.itemID AS Expr1, 
    dbo.item.Itemnumber, dbo.item.description, dbo.item.qty,     
    dbo.item.unitofmeasure, dbo.item.itid
FROM         
    dbo.memo 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.item ON dbo.memo.memID = dbo.item.itid
WHERE
    (dbo.memo.department = N'tsd')
```

and output is this

[this is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5sRO.jpg)

I just want 1 output of the fullname, company, department, MRnum, date , remarks, issuedby every multiple rows of item

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9jFF.jpg)

Hope you understand . thank you

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT... But duplicates in INNER JOIN usually mean your data is not normalized

Comment: can you show us your expected output ? Sounds to me you only want to show fullname, company etc on one line and empty for the rest of the lines

Comment: @Squirrel , there are multiple data in item that is bind to memo , i want the output to be like this , 1 name with multiple items ..

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DISTINCT` in your query.

See below

```
SELECT DISTINCT     dbo.memo.memID, dbo.memo.fullname, dbo.memo.company, dbo.memo.department, dbo.memo.MRnum, dbo.memo.date, dbo.memo.returndate, dbo.memo.remarks, dbo.memo.issuedby, dbo.memo.picture, dbo.item.itemID AS Expr1, dbo.item.Itemnumber, dbo.item.description, dbo.item.qty, dbo.item.unitofmeasure,                       dbo.item.itid 
FROM   dbo.memo 
   INNER JOIN dbo.item ON dbo.memo.memID = dbo.item.itid 
WHERE     (dbo.memo.department = N'tsd')
```

Answer (score 0):

> i just want , 1 output of the fullname, company, department, MRnum,
>   date , remarks, issuedby with multiple rows of item

You could do this, use `group by` on required columns and take `top 1`

```
SELECT  TOP 1
        dbo.memo.fullname ,
        dbo.memo.company ,
        dbo.memo.department ,
        dbo.memo.MRnum ,
        dbo.memo.date ,
        dbo.memo.remarks ,
        dbo.memo.issuedby
FROM    dbo.memo
INNER JOIN dbo.item
        ON dbo.memo.memID = dbo.item.itid
WHERE   ( dbo.memo.department = N'tsd' )
GROUP BY dbo.memo.fullname ,
        dbo.memo.company ,
        dbo.memo.department ,
        dbo.memo.MRnum ,
        dbo.memo.date ,
        dbo.memo.remarks ,
        dbo.memo.issuedby
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use `TOP` like below if you are **certain** you get all duplicate records.

```
SELECT TOP 1 dbo.memo.memID, dbo.memo.fullname, dbo.memo.company, dbo.memo.department, dbo.memo.MRnum, dbo.memo.date, dbo.memo.returndate, dbo.memo.remarks, dbo.memo.issuedby, dbo.memo.picture, dbo.item.itemID AS Expr1, dbo.item.Itemnumber, dbo.item.description, dbo.item.qty, dbo.item.unitofmeasure,                       dbo.item.itid 
FROM   dbo.memo 
   INNER JOIN dbo.item ON dbo.memo.memID = dbo.item.itid 
WHERE     (dbo.memo.department = N'tsd')
```

Comment: i want the output to be like this , 'fullname' , 'company' ,'department' , 'MRnum' , 'date' , multiple 'itemnumber' ,' description ', qty', unitofmeasure' ,